# wildflyserver giving error 404 when JavaServerFaces Authentication Filter code is compiled

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, xhtml

I am trying to run a simple program in which user is restricted to open any xhtml page if he is no logged in. I am using wildfly 10 server.

When i try to run the code these two errors appear on my console
/* console view*/

```
06:59:35,161 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JsfAuthentication.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JsfAuthentication.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.filter.loginFilter from [Module "deployment.JsfAuthentication.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.filter.loginFilter from [Module "deployment.JsfAuthentication.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:801)
    ... 6 more

06:59:35,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /Ddt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
06:59:35,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /CssDataTable
06:59:35,172 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /PreventAccessInJsf
06:59:36,877 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/UserAppForAddingUser'
06:59:36,892 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/UserWebApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
06:59:37,342 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /UserWebApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
06:59:37,345 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /UserAppForAddingUser
06:59:37,353 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "JsfAuthentication.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JsfAuthentication.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JsfAuthentication.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.filter.loginFilter from [Module \"deployment.JsfAuthentication.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.filter.loginFilter from [Module \"deployment.JsfAuthentication.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JsfAuthentication.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

/* My web.xml file consist of details about url patterns of filter*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>JsfAuthentication</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>project.filter.loginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

/*loginFilter. java class code where filter is defined*/

```
package project.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import project.web.bean;

public class loginFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        bean session = (bean) req.getSession().getAttribute("bean");
        String url = req.getRequestURI();

        if(session == null || !session.isLogged) {
            if(url.indexOf("forum.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("logout.xhtml") >= 0 ) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }else {
                chain.doFilter(request,response);   
            }
        }else {
            if(url.indexOf("register.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 ) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/forum.xhtml");
            }else if(url.indexOf("logout.xhtml") >= 0) {
                req.getSession().removeAttribute("bean");
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }else {
                chain.doFilter(request,response);
            }       
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: This filter has nothing to do with jsf. It is a plain servletfilter

Answer (score 0):

Since Servlet 3.0 you can use @WebFilter annotation. Instead declaring filter in **web.xml** try to do it with annotation. Code below.

```
package project.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import project.web.bean;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter(filterName="loginFilter")
public class loginFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        bean session = (bean) req.getSession().getAttribute("bean");
        String url = req.getRequestURI();

        if(session == null || !session.isLogged) {
            if(url.indexOf("forum.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("logout.xhtml") >= 0 ) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }else {
                chain.doFilter(request,response);   
            }
        }else {
            if(url.indexOf("register.xhtml") >= 0 || url.indexOf("login.xhtml") >= 0 ) {
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/forum.xhtml");
            }else if(url.indexOf("logout.xhtml") >= 0) {
                req.getSession().removeAttribute("bean");
                resp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
            }else {
                chain.doFilter(request,response);
            }       
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```